# How to filter string out from a list inside a list and append to a new list

Tags: python-3.x, list, append

I am trying to filter the data out from a list inside a list but not getting the expected output.

My List:

```
lnks = [['adsd%linkedin.comhasdhu', 'sahasbfacebook.comdcs', 'dfsdftwitter.comdsddf'],
['vsdd%linkedin.comfsadfs', 'sdfsdfsfacebook.comsfsdf', '345r3ftwitter.comwer'],
['fvsdlinkedin.comsdfsf', 'sdfefacebook.comswwert', 'wtwtwitter.comy4w4y']]
```

My Code:

```
linkedin = []
twitter = []
facebook = []

for lnk in lnks:
    if "linkedin" in lnk:
        try:
            linkedin.append(lnk)
        except:
            linkedin.append("")
    elif "twitter" in lnk:
        try:
            twitter.append(lnk)
        except:
            twitter.append("")
    elif "facebook" in lnk:
        try:
            facebook.append(lnk)
        except:
            facebook.append("")
```

Expected Output:

```
linkedin = ['adsd%linkedin.comhasdhu','vsdd%linkedin.comfsadfs','fvsdlinkedin.comsdfsf']
twitter = ['dfsdftwitter.comdsddf', '345r3ftwitter.comwer', 'wtwtwitter.comy4w4y']
facebook = ['sahasbfacebook.comdcs', 'sdfsdfsfacebook.comsfsdf', 'sdfefacebook.comswwert']
```

Comment: `lnk` is always a *list* of strings, none of which are *just* the name of one of these services.

Comment: Why do you think `append` might fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because your original dataset is a list of list. If you step through your code using the debugger you will see that lnk is a list, not a string like I think you expect. So your *if* condition is never being met, and nothing is appended.

You can also do this more succinctly by doing:

```
lnks = [['adsd%linkedin.comhasdhu', 'sahasbfacebook.comdcs', 'dfsdftwitter.comdsddf'],
['vsdd%linkedin.comfsadfs', 'sdfsdfsfacebook.comsfsdf', '345r3ftwitter.comwer'],
['fvsdlinkedin.comsdfsf', 'sdfefacebook.comswwert', 'wtwtwitter.comy4w4y']]

linkedin = [[a for a in b if 'linkedin' in a][0] for b in lnks]
twitter = [[a for a in b if 'twitter' in a][0] for b in lnks]
facebook = [[a for a in b if 'facebook' in a][0] for b in lnks]

print(f'Linkedin: {linkedin}')
print(f'Twitter: {twitter}')
print(f'Facebook: {facebook}')
```

---

```
# Output
Linkedin: ['adsd%linkedin.comhasdhu', 'vsdd%linkedin.comfsadfs', 'fvsdlinkedin.comsdfsf']
Twitter: ['dfsdftwitter.comdsddf', '345r3ftwitter.comwer', 'wtwtwitter.comy4w4y']
Facebook: ['sahasbfacebook.comdcs', 'sdfsdfsfacebook.comsfsdf', 'sdfefacebook.comswwert']
```

---

Sometimes nested inline for loops with conditions can look confusing but it breaks down like this:

```
lnks = list of lists
b = list
a = string
# we specify [0] so that we end up returning 1 list populated with strings, and not another list of lists.
```

Answer (score 1):

```
linkedin = []
twitter = []
facebook = []

for lnk in lnks:
    for lnk2 in lnk:
        if "linkedin" in lnk2:
            try:
                linkedin.append(lnk2)
            except:
                linkedin.append("")
        elif "twitter" in lnk2:
            try:
                twitter.append(lnk2)
            except:
                twitter.append("")
        elif "facebook" in lnk2:
            try:
                facebook.append(lnk2)
            except:
                facebook.append("")
```

This should get the required output

Answer (score 0):

If they are always going to be in that order, you could go with a `zip`:

```
lnks = [['adsd%linkedin.comhasdhu', 'sahasbfacebook.comdcs', 'dfsdftwitter.comdsddf'],
['vsdd%linkedin.comfsadfs', 'sdfsdfsfacebook.comsfsdf', '345r3ftwitter.comwer'],
['fvsdlinkedin.comsdfsf', 'sdfefacebook.comswwert', 'wtwtwitter.comy4w4y']]

linkedin, twitter, facebook = list(zip(*lnks))
```

The output looks like:

```
print(linkedin, twitter, facebook, sep="\n\n")


('adsd%linkedin.comhasdhu', 'vsdd%linkedin.comfsadfs', 'fvsdlinkedin.comsdfsf')

('sahasbfacebook.comdcs', 'sdfsdfsfacebook.comsfsdf', 'sdfefacebook.comswwert')

('dfsdftwitter.comdsddf', '345r3ftwitter.comwer', 'wtwtwitter.comy4w4y')
```